# Can I avoid multiple inheritance here?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I am in a situation where I'm going to do a multiple inheritance (and the diamond of dread kind of). I'd like to avoid that, so hopefully someone has an idea to do it another way.

I want to make a library that handle network connections. I have an abstract factory with method to create a tcpServer, tcpClient, udp, and a last method that create an entry from a directory (config file is given to the init method of the factory). So I've created classes (actually interfaces) to this kind of connections. Entry is the base interface. To simplify, let's just say that it has methods to set data and status callback. All other classes (tcpClient ...) inherits from this one.

I want to do an implementation of this factory using boost, so I have to implement all the classes (tcpServer, …). The problem is that all class implementations require a common base. Here is what I'm going to do, but I'm not sure that's the right way to do it:

Here is the abstract part:

```
// The abstract factory:
class Factory
{
    virtual IO::TcpServer* createTcpServer() = 0;
    virtual IO::TcpClient* createTcpClient() = 0;

    virtual IO::Entry* createFromConf() = 0;
};  


// The Entry interface: 
class Entry {
    virtual bool isChild() const = 0;
    // ...

    virtual void setDataCbk() = 0;
    virtual void setStateCbk() = 0;
};

// TcpClient interface
class TcpClient : public IO::Entry {
    /* Nothing yet but stuff will come */
};
```

Here is the boost implementation (Class names are same but in different namespaces; I don't show the factory implementation):

```
// Entry first step of implementation (still abstract)
class Entry : public IO::Entry
{
    virtual void setDataCbk();
    virtual void setStateCbk();
};

// Flat entry : entry that can't have child (like tcp client, udp ...)
class FlatEntry : public IO::Boost::Entry
{
    virtual bool isChild() const; // Will always return false
    // ...
};

// The final TcpClient implementation
class TcpClient : public IO::TcpClient
            , public IO::Boost::FlatEntry
{
    // ...
};
```

So I'm worried about this multiple inheritance thing. On the other hand, super classe is a pure interface (no data, only pure virtual methods). Any ideas?

Comment: The dread diamond is only an issue if the shared portion has data, apart from some casts going awry.

Comment: No diamond. Both children have their own unique `Entry` parent.

Comment: The lack of `virtual` in the inheritance implies to me that the above won't compile.  Remove any `...` from your examples please.  As an example, `::Entry` isn't purely abstract, did you intend to use `=0` in those signatures?  Or is `::Entry` a mix-in implementation class?  As a mind reader, I'm guessing you want more `virtual` inheritance, and you are trying to describe "mix-in" implementations?

Comment: @LokiAstari `Boost::TcpClient` inherits from `IO::TcpClient` and `Boost::FlatEntry`. Both of theses classes inherits from `IO::Entry`

Comment: @Yakk Sorry I made a mistake in my code example. `FlatEntry` inherits from `IO::Boost::Entry` and not `IO::Entry`. I didn't know about virtual inheritance, thanks for the tip. However, I don't understand what you mean by "mix-in" implémentation ?

Comment: @Yakk: The lack of virtual will not stop it from compiling. You use virtual to define what is a shared parent rather than a unique parent.

Comment: @DenisB: Without virtual inheritance the parents are not shared. Thus they are unique thus no diamond. To be honest I see no need for virtual inheritance in this example. So don't add it.

Comment: @LokiAstari except the base class had 3 pure `virtual` methods.  The left branch overrode 2, the right branch overrode 1, and the most-derived overrode none.  That left 3 methods unimplemented.  So the most-derived "final implementation" could not be instantiated.  Admittedly, failure to compile would only occur when a the OP tried to actually create an object.

Comment: "All other objects inherit from this one" -- sure, but why?  Why are tcp servers and clients the same kind of object?  What is an "entry"?   There are many reasons to have diamond inheritance with mixins -- a mixin is a partial implementation of some interface that you can mix in with other partial implementations to create a final implementation.  There are also many reasons why you don't want to do this.  Details matter.

Comment: @Yakk: virtual methods have nothing to do with virtual inheritance. There is **NO** diamond inheritance here. Opps sorry. We seem to be arguing at tangents. You mean it wont compile because the methods are pure virtual.

Comment: @lokiastari yes, they are pure virtual.  With virtual inheritance all pure virtual members above are implemented.  Without, some are not.  Hence, as I said originally, OP needs virtual inheritance to make the sample code compile.  Which makes it a diamond.